# Looping through all list of posts not in some category in liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I want to loop through posts on a site except ones with the category `unlisted`. I'm able to do this by nesting an if statement inside the for loop, but this breaks down when I want to also specify a `limit` – the loop will run for 5 times only regardless of whether the post passes the check.

```
{% for post in site.posts limit: 5 %}
  {% unless post.categories contains 'unlisted' %}
  <!-- display post -->
  {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

I need to pass an already filtered list to the for loop, but I'm unable to do this mainly because I can't find a way to combine the `where` filter with `contains` and negation:

```
{% for post in site.posts | WHERE CATEGORIES NOT CONTAINS 'UNLISTED' | limit: 5 %}
  <!-- display post -->
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a counter :

```
<ul>
{% assign postCounter = 0 %}
{% assign maxPost = 5 %}
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% unless post.categories contains 'unlisted' %}
    <li><a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% assign postCounter = postCounter | plus: 1 %}
    {% if postCounter >= maxPost %}
      {% break %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```